# Pass dynamic variable from HTML to less.css file

Tags: jquery, css, less

I've just started using Less. I am now looking to change background color as per a value passed from the  HTML file. For example in HTML file select blue color than all background set blue and if select yellow than all background set Yellow.

The mechanism is to change color for look and fill. User can change his theme as per his requirement. So when user changes the color all theme of site color should be changed.
Below is how I was thinking of passing the selected color

[image: In this snapshot Html Select blue Color]

And this is how I expect the value to be assigned in the less.css file.

[image: In this snapshot less file description]

So, How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Modifying vars from the front-end is not recommended as per Less website. How many such color options do you have? Can't you create static classes for each color?

Comment: For the most part, LESS is compiled prior to rendering in the browser. So there's no communication between the HTML and LESS files once it's served to the end user. It's more likely that you'll want to use Javascript to toggle a new "theme" class when the button is pressed. Add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish (what's the mechanism for changing colors / why) and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: hi,harry.. there are 20 color available.. so can i make static class for each color??

Comment: The mechanism to change color for look and fill. wise user can change his theme as per his requirement.. so when user change the color all theme of site color should be change.

Comment: hi, For Example In drop down  there are multiple color available now user can change whatever color that pass in the less file and change that color in page dynamically.. than how can achieve this.. using less..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to do something like the following:

- Give the user a pre-defined list of theme colors to choose from (a drop-down maybe). Don't allow for entering any color they wish to, that would be a pain.
- When the select any color append, the color name to the `body` as a `class` using jQuery/JS.
- In Less, write the below code, compile it statically and link the compiled CSS to your page.

  ```
  body { 
    background-color: red; /* default */
    &.red {background-color: red;} 
    &.green{background-color: green;} 
    &.blue{background-color: blue;}
  }
  ```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#color-chooser').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.body.className = this.value;
  });
}
```

```css
/* compiled CSS based on the Less code provided above */

body {
  background-color: red;
  /* default */
}
body.red {
  background-color: red;
}
body.green {
  background-color: green;
}
body.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label>Select Background Color:</label>
<select id='color-chooser'>
  <option value='red'>Red</option>
  <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
  <option value='green'>Green (Hex)</option>
</select>
```

---

Alternately, if you insist on doing it dynamically via the front-end then you  can use `modifyVars` option:

Note that I wouldn't recommend this option as the [Less website itself states that it should be used only when there is no other choice](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser).

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Select Background Color:</label>
  <select id='color-chooser'>
    <option value='red'>Red</option>
    <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
    <option value='#0F0'>Green (Hex)</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.querySelector('#color-chooser').addEventListener('change', function(){
      less.modifyVars({ /* this sets the color to the variable */
        '@bgcolor': this.value
      });
    });
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.less:**

```
body {
  background-color: @bgcolor;
}
@bgcolor: red;
```

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/eN9c69GmATZ6TuauQ9M7?p=preview) (*couldn't put this into a snippet*)

Comment: @RaviShah: You don't need 15 rep for accepting. That limit is only for voting. You can accept by just clicking that tick mark.